# RavenDB InvalidOperationException "The query results type is '<Document>' but you expected to get results of type '<IndexResult>' "

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to follow the Indexing Tutorial "Example II" for a DocumenQuery from 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/map-indexes

And get the following InvalidOperationException:

*"The query results type is 'Resource' but you expected to get results of type 'Result'. If you want to return a projection, you should use .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto() (for Query) or .SelectFields() (for DocumentQuery) before calling to .ToList()."*

I fail how my setup is different from the documentation.

I have an index setup like this:

```
    public class ResourceIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Raven.Resource>
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string[] Query { get; set; }
        }


        public ResourceIndex()
        {
            Map = resources => from resource in resources
                               select new
                               {
                                   Query = new[]
                                    {
                                        resource.ID.ToString(),
                                    }
                               };

            Index("Query", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }

...
```

And query it like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Raven.Resource> QueryAssets(string searchTerm)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = dataStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var resources = session
                .Advanced
                .DocumentQuery<ResourceIndex.Result, ResourceIndex>()
                .Search(x => x.Query, searchTerm).OfType<Raven.Resource>().ToList();

            return resources;
        }
    }
```

What am i missing in my setup vs the documentation about how to use an index in combination whith DocumentQuery and .Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add after `Search` `.SelectField<Raven.Resource>()` and it will work like the exception suggested. Your query should look something like this

```
var resources = session
                        .Advanced
                        .DocumentQuery<ResourceIndex.Result, ResourceIndex>()
                        .Search(x => x.Query, searchTerm).SelectFields<Raven.Resource>().ToList();
```

You didn't miss anything in the documentation for now just remove the `OfType()` and use only the `SelectFields`
For the Query `OfType` works the same as `SelectFields` so if you use this your Query suppose to look like this:

```
session.Query<ResourceIndex.Result, ResourceIndex>()
.Search(x => x.Query, "2").OfType<Resource>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late to the party, but I thought the reason for the error is this:

You've declared:

```
public class ResourceIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Raven.Resource>
```

this says: *Create an Index, based off the document `Raven.Resource` and it will end up returning results that are of type `Raven.Resource`.*

and then in your code, to use this index, you've said:

```
.DocumentQuery<ResourceIndex.Result, ResourceIndex>()
```

this says: *Query the Index `ResourceIndex` and I expect `ResourceIndex.Result` documents to be returned.*

But ... this is wrong. Then index contains `Raven.Resource` documents, not `ResourceIndex.Result` documents.

Comment: thanks for answering - I am not working with Raven anymore and have no way to verify the answer. Hopefully it will be useful to someone else!

Comment: No problems @Richard - I was expecting possibly as much. It was more for other people who might stumble across this question. Good luck!